# CM10.1 now cannot record any inbound audio on phone calls

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, call-recording

```
CM10.1 now cannot record any inbound audio on phone calls
```

I was running Jellybean stock on my i9300 and used Total Recall to record telephone calls, recording both inbound and outbound audio correctly. I have now flashed CM10.1 and tried Total Recall to record telephone calls and I can no longer call inbound conversation.

I have also tried Sanity, Call Recorder Demo and Digital Call Record. Whenever I change the source for each of these respective programs to MIC everything works - except of course I cannot clearly record the inbound audio (the voice of the person on the other end).

When testing this I was sure to uninstall the other recording applications as I understand that 2 or more recording applications may cause conflict.

Any ideas about what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to, as far as I know, Cyanogenmod policies.. In some countries call recording is illegal and therefore CM team hasn't implemented this feature. It's really annoying because the issue applies to certain (but not all) regions of the world.

I do hope that CM developers will come up with some sort of hack in the future. For now I am using Auto Call Recorder (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder) and using Mic as a source. The volume of inbound audio is very low unless the mic is turned on during the call.

Call recording is the only feature I lack in CM...

Comment: Thanks for the response Juozas. At least I know it's a policy rather than a config error on my end.

Comment: Can you give link where CyanogenMod said they have reason for removing? Thats not a reason and that reason is false. Even if it would be illeagal to record, just adding code doesnt make CyanogenMod makers doing it. BTW originally Android can record so Samsung also isnt doing anything illeagal.

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of successfully enabled call recording of both inbound and out bound using Callrecorder and ALSA. The problem I have is callrecorder crashes multiple times during the phone call and restarts another session.

Answer (score 0):

I faced also same problem after update with CM 10 but as I updated with CM 12 so total recall call recorder is working again or should I say it's working amazingly. And it can record a phone call continuously.

Also one thing i must say that It can be possible because of total recall app updates too.
I got the latest version from here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.killermobile.totalrecall

Comment: Your wording seems to be promotional. Are you affiliated to this product? I recall a user named "Sonal Chouhan" who also posted SPAM a month ago or so.